# Is my opinion-removing edit legit?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317115/shell-replacements-stall-inside-of-shared-vagrant-folder) had possibly a nice dig in it.

> I wanted to migrate over to fish or zsh *due to them being way better then default bash* [emphasis mine]

I thought the italicized part could easily be taken as *fish and zsh is better than bash amirite?!* and, since it wasn't salient to the question itself, I removed it. But I'm a little hesitant, so I figured I'd get a second opinion here.

Was I right to remove that part, or too zealous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too zealous. The opinionated remark was doing no real harm, and what's more, it added a piece of information: that the shell being replaced was the default shell, Bash. This:

- Makes clear that the user hasn't *already* replaced the default shell with something *else* besides fish or zsh
- Communicates to people familiar with Ubuntu that the shell being replaced is Bash (used by default for the interactive terminal), not Dash (the default shell for everything else, which `/bin/sh` is a symlink to, and which is therefore used by default by many of the OS's startup scripts and by shell invocations from many programming languages, like `shell_exec` in PHP). This seems like very important information to preserve, and is probably sufficient justification for a rollback.
- Conveys to people familiar with *nix but not Ubuntu that Bash is one of the default shells in Ubuntu

Even if you'd only edited out the opinion, and not removed the information that the shell being replaced was Bash, I'd still be vaguely against the edit. The remark provided some general flavour about the motivation behind the asker's actions, which while not strictly necessary may be interesting to answerers ("why did this guy even want to do this weird thing I just helped him with?") and makes readers casually aware of the fact that some folks consider fish and zsh so much better than bash that they're worth swapping to. If the opinionated stuff were some lengthy rant, then sure, it might deserve to be culled. But if a throwaway remark can succinctly communicate a little bit of general information to people about alternative tools to the ones they're used to using, and the feelings and opinions of (some) people on those tools, then isn't it nice to preserve that information as long as there's little enough of it that it doesn't meaningfully distract from the main point of the post?

Questions should be direct and to the point, but that needn't mean stripping every tiny extraneous detail from every post. Similarly, posts shouldn't be chatty or ranty, but that needn't mean diligently purging all evidence that any Stack Overflow poster has an opinion or a soul.

Comment: I've gone ahead and rolled back since I think the grounds given in my second bullet point are pretty compelling. I won't touch the question any further, though, in the interests of not edit-warring.